# Netlogo Export World as ACII file

Tags: netlogo

Can I export the final view of my map as a file that i can then input on a GIS software?

The export section on the basic netlogo manual wasnt useful

Comment: I think you may have already done this but if you have not, it may be helpful to check out the NetLogo GIS extension: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html

Comment: There is some info, but ill have to play around to take full advantage. Thanks